# Indesign: Master pages not applying correctly in the right order

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm guessing this is a pretty simple problem I'm having. I'm new to indesign and can't figure out how the masters apply to the pages properly.

For example, I have a 3 page master and I drag down the first page - fine; I drag down the second page - fine; I drag down the third page and the first page displays instead of the third. It also happens when I try to put the first page of a 2-page spread on the right-hand page.

Is there a setting I need checked or unchecked for this? What am I doing wrong? Sorry if this is a really simple problem.

Edit: [image: Image of problem]

Comment: This behavior is quite logical. You see the first page of your master spread applied to the first spread of your live pages.

Comment: I don't find it logical when trying to make a booklet full of different lengthed articles.

Comment: But the *spread page count* is what counts here. When I use a similar scheme I make sure to have both left and right "first" pages and "next" pages.

Comment: *Most* booklets don't contain 3 page spreads. The logic is sound, your layout is non-standard so you have to use a non-standard set up.

Comment: Why would a booklet not have a 3 page spread? I'm trying to work out what I'm doing wrong. What should I have done?

Comment: By definition a booklet contains only right and left pages. In order to produce a 3 page spread in a booklet, you'd need an extra fold. In addition, that 3rd page would be narrower so when it folds inward it doesn't buckle. How many 3-page spread booklets have you seen??? In reality the Playboy centerfold is the only multi-page spread I've ever seen on the interior of a book or magazine. There's a reason it's rare.

Comment: I meant a saddle-stitched booklet, not one folded into 3 pages. But within that I have 3 page articles. Just a standard 40 page booklet. All I was wanting was for the Q master to run across 3 pages.

Comment: Then you wouldn't have 3 master pages. A saddle-stitched booklet, without any additional folding should **only have right and left** master pages. You should never have a 3-page spread anywhere in a saddle stitched booklet. Master pages are designed to reflect the production set up.

Comment: Just because an article takes up 3 pages of a book, it does not mean it needs a 3-page master page. Your screenshot shows the Q master on 3 pages correctly for a standard saddle-stitched booklet. You honestly do not need that third Q master page.

Comment: 3 pages taking up 3 master pages is what I find logical. If I dont need the 3rd page then where does the content go? There's something fundamental I'm missing here.

Comment: I knew you were getting annoyed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm just trying to help. But being met with a brick wall makes it a bit difficult. You're logic is flawed and may create production nightmares. But if you aren't interested in how to do things properly, it's okay. I'll let it go.

Comment: The reason I'm here is I'm trying to learn. It's why I'm asking questions.

Comment: Okay in a booklet.. there are *only* left and right pages. That's all. So your masters should *only* be left and right pages. If you have an article which spans 3 pages it would fall on a left-right-left or right-left-right page order. Your screenshot above shows things correctly. You can delete the 3rd page for the Q master, you really do not need it.

Comment: Don't think about the length of articles when configuring master pages. It does not matter how many pages an article takes. The master pages should still only be a left and right page.

Comment: If you need a special master page for the 3rd page of an article, then you need to configure a special single-page master. So when the article hits left-right-left you can apply that single page master to that last left page. So, at best you need 1 double-page master and 1 single page master, but *never* a 3-page master.

Comment: What I don't understand is when you say I can delete the 3rd master page. Then where does that 3rd page of content go? This is how I got it to work. Is it wrong? [link](http://s21.postimg.org/5wi5vgy7r/indesign3.jpg)

Comment: Master pages are not designed for varying page content. You don't put the article text on the master pages. You only put things on master pages which will not change on every page. The article text should be on your *pages* not the masters. If you've got the article text on the master pages, *that* may be where you are struggling. And **yes** that image is wrong and will cause issues in production.

Comment: It sounds like you are merely using Master Pages incorrectly and that's causing problems with your layout. You will need to start over and move the article text from the master pages to the actual pages first. You can copy/paste. The master pages should **only** contain things like page numbers, or running headers that you want to be consistent across *all* pages.

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Facing pages** are used to control the logic of master pages as well as the layout in the Pages Panel. With Facing Pages on, the masters become "right" and "left" not 1 and 2. So InDesign will not let you place a left master on the right page. The logic, to me, seems to be there to prevent a user from mistakenly applying the wrong master page to something.

You need a 3 page spread in the Pages panel, set up like the 3p master, to apply that 3rd Q master to it. Then it'll allow you to apply 2 left pages and the 3rd right page.

If you want absolute control over what master page is applied where, you need to turn off Facing Pages and create individual masters then manually place pages in spreads. As non-facing pages, with single page masters, Indesign will allow you to apply any master page to any other page.

Comment: If your master is a spread, you still only get the Left-hand page when Facing Pages is turned off. You would need single-page masters, not spread masters.

Comment: did a quick test in CS6 and it did not show that behavior.

Comment: Yup.. just did the same thing. I was incorrect. You need single page master as well as non-facing pages. I edited this answer.

Comment: I can't believe you need single page masters :O Thank you both for your help.

Comment: Click-drag a page to the spread. You may need to check/uncheck "Allow Document Pages to Shuffle" in the Pages Panel menu.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to place a three-page spread master page into a two-page spread. As far as I know, InDesign will copy text from a master not page-by-page but by spread.

You can't drag text from a master page (even though you can highlight a single page in a spread). When you attempt to drag the master page it will automatically fill all available pages in the destination spread by beginning at the first page of the master.

One solution is to make the third page of Q-Master its own master page, then copy it to page 18.

Comment: When I add a 2 page spread on the right hand page this happens: [link]  (s1.postimg.org/t43udyanj/indesign2.jpg) Surely there's a setting that fixes this rather than splitting all your spreads into 1 page spreads? Either that or I'm doing something wrong, which is highly likely. Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm... That's peculiar. So (correct me if I'm wrong here), you are applying U-Master to page 11 and it's inverting the order?

Comment: Yeah I want U-Master on 11 and 12 and it's displaying back to front.

Comment: Okay, this is the same issue as the three page spread; now's it's reduced to a two page issue.

InDesign is copying by spread. So the 2nd page in U-Master will only be applied as the 2nd page in any spread, never the first. Maybe there's a way around this, but I don't have enough experience to know.